# How to connect to my old account which was using OpenID

Tags: discussion, login

I've noticed today that users can't use OpenID for login anymore. I have an old account with linked only to OpenID.

How I can login into my old Stack Overflow profile now?

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4969827/panda)? It appears linked to this account of yours, you should be able to use it. Or you mean you have an even older account on SO, not linked to this one?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, I created this account temporary to ask this question. Original profile is - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2956344/sergey-shustikov

Comment: Well, you should merge it then. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous), not sure how it works with the recent change of stopping to support OpenID though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can't specify profile links. I pointed both as StackExchange profiles but it gives me an error :  "oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile"

Comment: Please go to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), choose "I need to merge profiles" under "What can we help you with?", and put `https://stackoverflow.com/users/2956344/sergey-shustikov` under "Your other profile link".